# How to achieve dependent foreign keys listing in django-admin?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-admin-filters

Suppose I have 3 models:- Address, Country, State
Address Model:

```
class AddressModel(BaseModel):
    country = models.ForeignKey(CountryModel, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    state = models.ForeignKey(StateModel, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    pincode = models.CharField(max_length=6, null=True, blank=True)
    address_line_1 = models.TextField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    address_line_2 = models.TextField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
```

Country Model:

```
class CountryModel(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

and State Model:

```
class StateModel(BaseModel):
    country = models.ForeignKey(CountryModel, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

While adding a new address in django admin, I want to show the list of only those states which belong to the selected country  i.e I want to implement something like dependent foreign key list in django-admin.
I would like to achieve it without using jquery or ajax
How can I do that?

Comment: probably you can't do that without js/jquery/ajax

Comment: ok
how can i achieve this with ajax

Comment: There some blogs like this one which might help you: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html

Comment: I want to do this in admin